# Inner workings of LiveData

Tags: android

If I call `LiveData.setValue()` before any observers are attached.

Then I attach an observer like so, `LiveData.observe(...)` will the `onChanged()` method still be called, or it will only be called if I observe before setValue?

Comment: I think it called immediately if live data already has value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documents of LiveData method observe you can check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData)

> Adds the given observer to the observers list within the lifespan of the given owner. The events are dispatched on the main thread. If LiveData already has data set, it will be delivered to the observer.